# Vaadin 8 - WARNING: Adding listeners with type Object is deprecated, event listener should extend SerializableEventListener

Tags: vaadin, warnings, vaadin8

I have noted a large number of warnings in my Tomcat server log.  I have checked my listeners, and don't know what this references.  I am running Vaadin 8.13.0 on Java 14:

```
May 19, 2021 2:32:09 PM com.vaadin.event.EventRouter addListener
WARNING: Adding listeners with type Object is deprecated, event listener should extend SerializableEventListener
```

Is there a way to find out details about where this message is being emitted (like a stack trace) so that I can troubleshoot/fix it?  As it is, it doesn't provide any information for me to find where an Object event listener is being used.

Thanks

Comment: Here is [the commit](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/commit/40570e17319d96adcfebaaa8c98b1e16f58902f0#diff-33cc4a00066f63bd2140833dbf62d9d7b731a6988c1237ad8a3c4baefbd73ab3) that added it, maybe it will shed some light on the situation.

Comment: I believe the warning is that you should use the more specific `addValueChangeListener`, `addClickListener` methods etc instead of the generic `addListener` API

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to find out details about where this message is being emitted (like a stack trace)

To find a stack trace in a situation like this, I would recommend setting a breakpoint on the line of code that logs the warning and then running your application in a debugger to see how that line is reached.

If you cannot easily run the application in a debugger, then an alternative approach might be to include your own copy of `EventRouter.java` in your application but modify the code in it to throw an exception instead of only logging a warning. Assuming the classpath is correctly configured, then Java will pick up your version from the classpath and use it instead of the original one from Vaadin.

Comment: Great advice on adding breakpoints (there were 3 places in EventRouter.java).  I was able to track at least one down to the add on PopupButton 3.0.0 by 'hene' (Henri Kerola) at https://vaadin.com/directory/component/popupbutton/3.0.0

Answer (score 1):

This warning is due some add-on component. For example if you use ContextMenu add-on in your project its listener will cause this logging to happen. This in most cases harmless, and should not be a major concern, the add-ons do still work. There are some applications where strict serializability is required and hence if custom components or add-ons do not implement the right interface, this target is not achieved. Purpose of the warning is to get attention of add-on developers to update their add-ons to implement correct interfaces and rebuild add-ons against Vaadin 8.13. For example there is a new version of ContextMenu add-on already, but it takes time for community to react and update. We may drop the level of the logging to something less prominent as over time it has served its purpose.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to track at least one down to the add on PopupButton 3.0.0 by 'hene' (Henri Kerola) at vaadin.com/directory/component/popupbutton/3.0.0

Comment: You could create an issue about it in https://github.com/henrikerola/PopupButton/issues